# Implementing multiple routing in React

Tags: reactjs, routes

I want to implement two layouts: one is Login Component and another is the Dashboard component. Both have different layouts.

So in App.js, I have the main Routing within Switch, like so:
"/"
"/sign-up"
"/forgot-password"
"/dashboard"

Now in "/dashboard", I have Dashboard Component, which has another Routing component within a Switch. But here, this is happening right now.
"/dashboard/library"
"/dashboard/media"

So if I want to go to Library Component which is a child component of Dashboard, the URL becomes, "/dashboard/library"

How can I make the URL to only "/library". Is there is something I am missing or that am I implementing it wrong?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the way that I handle these kinds of situations is by giving the responsibility of routing to Dashboard router without any path.
 like this:

```
<Switch>
   <Route exact path={"/"} render={() => <h1>home</h1>} />
   <Route exact path={"/login"} render={() => <h1>login</h1>} />
   <DashboardRouter />
</Switch>
```

just don't forget 404 page in **DashboardRouter**
complete example:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
const DashboardRouter = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path={"/dashboard"} render={() => <h1>dashboard</h1>} />
      <Route path={"/library"} render={() => <h1>library</h1>} />
      <Route render={() => <h1>Not Found</h1>} />

    </Switch>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
        <Link to={"/"}>home</Link>
        <Link to={"/login"}>login</Link>
        <Link to={"/dashboard"}>dashboard</Link>
        <Link to={"/library"}>library</Link>
        <Link to={"/not-found"}>not found</Link>
      </div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={"/"} render={() => <h1>home</h1>} />
        <Route exact path={"/login"} render={() => <h1>login</h1>} />
        <DashboardRouter />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

you can find the live version of code in the code sandbox too:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dashboard-router-wkjkx?file=/src/App.js
please let me know if you still have any problem